# SQL: index on "order by" column when a query also has a lot of "where" predicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Suppose I have this sql query:

```
select * from my_table
where col1 = 'abc' and col2 = 'qwe' and ...  --e.g. 10 predicates or more
order by my_date desc
```

WIll the index only on `my_date` column even be used by DB? Will it improve performance somehow?

I'm more interested in Postgres.

Comment: It's unlikely that an index on *only* `my_date` will be used if any of the `where` predicates are indexed in a way that significantly reduces the rows to be scanned or sorted.  You can, however, index multiple columns; so, an index on `col1, col2, ..., my_date` may aid the `where` clause *and also* the `order by` clause, and so may then be chosen for use.

Comment: What is the cardinality of `col1` .. `col10` ? Why are there so many columns? Do they need to be indexed? What would be their *combined* cardinality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostgreSQL optimizer will use the index if it thinks that that is cheaper than fetching the rows that match the `WHERE` condition and sorting them.

This will probably be that case if:

- there are many such rows, and sorting would be more expensive than the index scan
- there are no indexes to support the `WHERE` condition

Comment: For the outer `ORDER BY`, the optimiser has few degrees of freedom. Its back is against the wall ...

Comment: Your answer seems to apply to  a LIMIT 1 situation (or maybe very low cursor_tuple_fraction), but his given query didn't include any LIMIT.

Comment: @jjanes Ah, you are right. I tried to fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without a LIMIT, the chances of using the single-column index to provide order here are pretty low.  Indeed, I can't contrive a situation to do so without monkeying around with `enable_sort` or `enable_seqsan`.

Even with a LIMIT, after applying 10 equality conditions it will be pretty unusual for the expected number of rows left over to be high enough to make the index appear to be worthwhile.